# Get Absolute Path of Each S3 Object in Bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Given an [AWSS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html), how can I get a complete list of all S3 Objects' paths?

Example:

Bucket Name: **foo** has 5 objects

- foo/bip/baz
- foo/bip/bap
- foo/bar/1
- foo/bar/2
- foo/1234

I'd like to get a `List[String]` consisting of those 5 items.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you call `listObjects(bucketName).getObjectSummaries()` then iterate over that list, calling `getKey()` ? If there are lots of objects, you also have to deal with the case that the ObjectListing is truncated, e.g. by using `listNextBatchOfObjects()`. Then just prepend `bucketName+ "/"` to each key.

Comment: Thanks, @DNA! Care to post for credit?

Comment: Glad that helped - have posted it as an answer now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you can call

```
listObjects(bucketName).getObjectSummaries()
```

on the `AmazonS3Client` object, then iterate over that list of object summaries, calling `getKey()` on each one.

(The `listObjects()` method returns an `ObjectListing`, and in turn the `getObjectSummaries()` method returns a `List<S3ObjectSummary>` - and each `S3ObjectSummary` contains the key!)

If there are lots of objects, you also have to deal with the case that the `ObjectListing` is truncated, e.g. by using `listNextBatchOfObjects()`. See also `ObjectListing.isTruncated()` ([javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#isTruncated%28%29)).

Finally, just prepend `bucketName+ "/"` to each key.